# Push Notifications Not appears in IOS (Phonegap, C#)

Tags: c#, ios, iphone, apple-push-notifications, phonegap-plugins

I'm trying send push notifications to APNS, debugging my server authenticates and sends the notification, but nothing appears on the iphone.

I'm using

```
<gap:plugin name="com.phonegap.plugins.pushplugin" version="2.4.0" />
```

I can catch the deviceToken to send the pushs with the following code:

```
if (device.platform == "iOS"){
        try
        {

        var pushNotification = window.plugins.pushNotification;

            if (pushNotification != undefined){
                pushNotification.register(
                    tokenHandler,
                    errorHandler, {
                        "badge":"true",
                        "sound":"true",
                        "alert":"true",
                        "ecb":"onNotificationAPN"
                    });                            
            }
        }
        catch(e)
        {
            alert('erro ao registrar ios: ' + e.message + ', stack: ' + e.stack);
        }
    }
```

OnNotification:

```
function onNotificationAPN(event) {
alert('notificationapn: ' + JSON.stringify(event));
try
{
if (event.alert)
{                                                            
    if (event.foreground == 1){
        if (event.alertaID != undefined){
            navigator.notification.alert(
                event.alertaCorpo,
                function(){ },
                'Mensagem de Incentivo',
                'Ok'
            );
        }                    
        else if (event.lembrete != undefined){
            navigator.notification.alert(
                event.alert,
                function(){ },
                'Lembrete',
                'Ok'
            ); 
        }
    }
    else
    {
        if (event.alertaID != undefined){
            mostraPopupAguarde();

            var mensagensIncentivo = new Array();
            var alerta = new Object();
            alerta.ID = event.alertaID;
            alerta.UrlImagem = event.alertaUrlImagem;
            alerta.Nome = event.alertaNome;
            alerta.Corpo = event.alertaCorpo;
            mensagensIncentivo.push(alerta);

            window.localStorage.setItem('mensagensIncentivo', JSON.stringify(mensagensIncentivo));

            carregaMensagemIncentivo(alerta.ID); 
            ocultaPopupAguarde();
        }
        else if (event.lembrete != undefined){
            navigator.notification.alert(
                event.alert,
                function(){ },
                'Lembrete',
                'Ok'
            ); 
        }
    }
}

if ( event.sound )
{
    var snd = new Media(event.sound);
    snd.play();
}

if ( event.badge )
{
    pushNotification.setApplicationIconBadgeNumber(successHandler, errorHandler, event.badge);
}
}
catch(e)
{
     alert('erro ao registrar ios: ' + e.message + ', stack: ' + e.stack);
}
```

}

and the code with token:

```
function tokenHandler(result) {       
//alert('Token: ' + result);
//I send token to the server.
}
```

My message from server to APNS:

```
{"aps":{"alert":"Você tem um(a) Hidracor agendado(a)!","badge":1,"sound":"new.caf"},"lembrete": true}
```

I downloaded the aps_development.cer and executed the following commands with openssl:

```
openssl x509 -in "aps_development.cer" -inform DER -out "path_to_an_output_Cert.pem" -outform PEM

openssl pkcs12 -export -inkey ios.key -in aps_development.pem -out aps_development.p12

openssl pkcs12 -nocerts -in "aps_development.p12" -out "path_to_an_output_Key.pem" -passin pass:mykey -passout pass:mykey

openssl pkcs12 -export -inkey "path_to_an_output_Key.pem" -in "path_to_an_output_Cert.pem" -out "pushCert.p12" -passin pass:mykey -passout pass:mykey
```

I use this file pushCert.p12  to authenticate via server with APNS.

I use this example to connect with the APNS:

http://apns-c-sharp-net-vikram-jain.blogspot.com.br/

Can anyone help me?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The problem was with my code, which I cited as an example, there was no significant change of the main methods. Then I tried another solution and found the MoonAPNS component, realized a change in the protocol that was using the SSL3 authentication to Default and that solved my problem.

```
_apnsStream.AuthenticateAsClient(host, certificates, System.Security.Authentication.SslProtocols.Default, false);
```